# grunt says no "sass" targets found

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I'm trying to set up grunt-contrib-sass so I can use grunt to handle sass-to-css compiling. I installed after scaffolding a basic grunt file with `grunt init:makefile`.  When I ran `grunt sass` just to test stuff, Terminal returns a "no "sass" targets found."

My setup:

- $sass -v returns "Sass 3.2.1"
- $ruby -v returns "ruby 1.9.3p194"
- the 'node_modules' folder contains 'grunt-contrib-sass'
- based on the grunt-contrib-sass docs, my grunt.js file currently looks like this:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
lint: {
  files: ['grunt.js', 'lib/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js']
},
test: {
  files: ['test/**/*.js']
},
watch: {
  files: '<config:lint.files>',
  tasks: 'lint test'
},
jshint: {
  options: {
    curly: true,
    eqeqeq: true,
    immed: true,
    latedef: true,
    newcap: true,
    noarg: true,
    sub: true,
    undef: true,
    boss: true,
    eqnull: true
  },
  globals: {},
   sass: {                                     // Task
    dist: {                                 // Target
        files: {                            // Dictionary of files
            'main.css': 'main.scss',        // 'destination': 'source'
            'widgets.css': 'widgets.scss'
        }
    },
    dev: {                                  // Another target
        options: {                          // Target options
            style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: {
            'main.css': 'main.scss',
            'widgets.css': [
                'button.scss',
                'tab.scss',
                'debug.scss'                
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

grunt.registerTask('default', 'lint sass');

};
```

Any and all help is appreciated...thanks much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double check your closing curly braces. Your `sass` block is within your `jshint` block. Try this:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
  lint: {
    files: ['grunt.js', 'lib/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js']
  },
  test: {
    files: ['test/**/*.js']
  },
  watch: {
    files: '<config:lint.files>',
    tasks: 'lint test'
  },
  jshint: {
    options: {
      curly: true,
      eqeqeq: true,
      immed: true,
      latedef: true,
      newcap: true,
      noarg: true,
      sub: true,
      undef: true,
      boss: true,
      eqnull: true
    },
    globals: {},
  },
  sass: {                                   // Task
    dist: {                                 // Target
        files: {                            // Dictionary of files
            'main.css': 'main.scss',        // 'destination': 'source'
            'widgets.css': 'widgets.scss'
        }
    },
    dev: {                                  // Another target
        options: {                          // Target options
            style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: {
            'main.css': 'main.scss',
            'widgets.css': [
                'button.scss',
                'tab.scss',
                'debug.scss'                
            ]
        }
    }
}
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

grunt.registerTask('default', 'lint sass');

};
```

Comment: A typical grunt newbie mistake on my part...thanx for your help!